# Kepping the rows and columns the same on small screens

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have `6` images in `2` rows and `3` columns over a background image. How can I keep this same layout on small screens?

In a responsive design on small screens the `6` images will line up vertically one under the other, as expected, but this is not what I need. I need to find a way to shrink the `6` images for the smaller screens while keeping them in the same `2` rows and `3` columns over a background image.

I can post code but I am using a `Python framework` which uses a `bootstrap framework` so if I post all the code it might just make things look more complicated. I am just looking for a simple `CSS` solution or perhaps a bootstrap solution if available.

Comment: You could just post the html output.

Comment: You mean to post the `View` from the Python framework?

Comment: Best solution is, If you want same view as in *Desktop*, then use *bootstrap* and use classes `col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4` on each image respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

http://www.bootply.com/YteNmihNaO

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://d.fastcompany.net/multisite_files/fastcompany/poster/2014/08/3034115-poster-p-1-the-monkey-selfie-question.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://d.fastcompany.net/multisite_files/fastcompany/poster/2014/08/3034115-poster-p-1-the-monkey-selfie-question.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://d.fastcompany.net/multisite_files/fastcompany/poster/2014/08/3034115-poster-p-1-the-monkey-selfie-question.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://d.fastcompany.net/multisite_files/fastcompany/poster/2014/08/3034115-poster-p-1-the-monkey-selfie-question.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://d.fastcompany.net/multisite_files/fastcompany/poster/2014/08/3034115-poster-p-1-the-monkey-selfie-question.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://d.fastcompany.net/multisite_files/fastcompany/poster/2014/08/3034115-poster-p-1-the-monkey-selfie-question.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to apply the same layout on all screen sizes you just need to specify the small media query like that:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
</div>
```